# Selecting Current Date

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have created following code for selecting the current date in the textbox.

```
$('#rstStartDTM').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date("01/01/1970"));
$('#rstStartDTM').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(
  new Date($.now()));
```

`rstStartDTM` is my `textbox` id.

But it is not reflecting in the textbox. Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: which plugin you are using datepicker or datetimepicker share any fiddle ?

Comment: @user2486 datetimepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this js fiddle :-
[Date picker default date](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/6059/)

```
$('#rstStartDTM').datetimepicker();
$('#rstStartDTM').data("DateTimePicker").date(new Date());
```

Comment: Did you know about minDate and maxDate?

Comment: @Prafulla What you want to do with minDate and maxDate?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#rstStartDTM').datepicker({
           dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
       });

   });
</script>
```

You can try this first and then in your textbox set attribute 
ClientIDMode="Static" and then set another attribute  AutoPostBack="True"